# geom_text screwing legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

As stated, I am trying to label some points in a graph but when I use the geom_text command, the legends get an "a" character behind.

```
ggplot(NewNMDS, aes(x=MDS1, y=MDS2, col=Temp)) +
   geom_point(size=2) +
   stat_ellipse() +
   theme_bw() +
   labs(title = "NMDS Plot")+ xlim(-1,1)
   geom_text(aes(label=Row.Names), vjust=1, hjust=0, nudge_x=0.01)
```

As you can see in the following plot, there is an "a" character overlapping with the legend line.

[image: NMDS plot screenshot]

The table that I'm using to plot this data has 5 rows (Row.Names, MDS1,MDS2,Biome and Temp). Since I'm trying to label the points, I added the row names into a column called "Row.Names" with the row names. I don't know if that is what's messing this up?

Comment: Include `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_text`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And yes, I looked for the answer and didn't find it but it definitely is a duplicate. My bad. Again, thanks for your answer.